# Stored procedure return conversion error when there should be no conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that just returns a `varchar(1000)`, but when I run using the following block:

```
declare @P1 VARCHAR(1000) 
SET @P1='' 
PRINT 'P1='+@P1
exec Test @PhoneNumber='1234567890',@AgentID=N'Test AgentID',@SP_RETURN=@P1 output  
PRINT 'P1='+@P1
```

I get

> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 50
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Complete' to data type int..
>
> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Test, Line 60
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Exception raised' to data type int.

This is the stored procedure:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]  
    @PhoneNumber as CHAR(10),  
    @AgentID as VARCHAR(100),  
    @SP_RETURN as VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,  
    @UTCDateTimeOverride as Datetime = NULL  
AS  
BEGIN  
 BEGIN TRY  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Complete'
  RETURN @SP_RETURN  
 END TRY  

 BEGIN CATCH  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Exception raised'
  RETURN @SP_RETURN  
 END CATCH  
END  
go
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stored procedure` always return integer, which is used to return the error code

you are returning a `varchar` field causing the exception

The error is caused by this

```
RETURN @SP_RETURN
```

do this instead

```
  BEGIN TRY  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Complete'
  RETURN 0  -- success
  END TRY  

  BEGIN CATCH  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Exception raised'
  RETURN  ERROR_NUMBER()  -- error code
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize that the return value is different from output variable. that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

A stored Procedure can only return an Int value. Varchar values are "returned" via OUTPUT variables.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]  
 @PhoneNumber as CHAR(10),  
 @AgentID as VARCHAR(100),  
 @SP_RETURN as VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT,  
 @UTCDateTimeOverride as Datetime = NULL  
AS  
BEGIN  
 BEGIN TRY  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Complete'
  --RETURN @SP_RETURN  not needed
 END TRY  

 BEGIN CATCH  
  SET @SP_RETURN = N'Exception raised'
  -- no need for return statement here 
 END CATCH  
END  
go
```

Now when executing the proc you will do something like ...

```
DECLARE @RETURN_Value VARCHAR(1000);

Exec [dbo].[Test]   @PhoneNumber = 'Some Value'  
                   ,@AgentID     = 'Some Value'
                   ,@SP_RETURN   = @RETURN_Value OUTPUT
```

Now the `@RETURN_Value` variable will have the values

Answer (score 0):

You're already specifying @SP_RETURN as OUTPUT.  You don't need it in your RETURN statements as well.  Just "RETURN"

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to use return in stored procedures just to give feedback is procedure executed successfully or not. To return values it is better it is better to use output parameters.

Using output parameters you are able to:
1.return more then 1 one value (using return you are able to return just one value);
2.return any data type (with return keyword you can return only int).